Is bike tyre pressure info deliberately hard to read?
Inflation pressures for tubes are typically written on the side wall of tyres.
I tend to use my tyres till they are very worn and tube starts to bulge through a tiny bit.
Most of the time I spot this condition because I'm inflating my tubes and scanning around the tyre wall for the hard to read pressure range.
My question is whether this is a design choice to make it more likely that people inspect their tyres properly?
I thought maybe it was cause the info tends to be much smaller and harder to read than branding info which tends to be in a contrasting colour, but that might just be because the same tyre is re-badged by multiple brands? (So branding info is added at a later stage than the size and pressure info which is part of the rubber mould itself)

I'd like to just point out that Velominati does not exist and therefore can't control how tire manufacturers mark their pressure recommendations. There is no conspiracy.

A slightly different take: having this kind of information from the mold rather than printed has a big advantage: it is more likely to be readable "after some time": paint that doesn't adhere well can chip over time (or in the case of off-road, can be removed if the tire rubs a stone/root), while molded information will probably remain. But I would think in practice, max pressure is not something that needs to be checked every time you inflate the tire: once you have settled for a pressure, you just inflate the tire to that pressure.

You can make pressure information easier to see by rubbing a white or silver Sharpie - indelible ink - pen on the raised writing. IT won't last forever but it does last a long time.

I find that licking your finger and running it over the surface of the writing makes it much easier to read

"I tend to use my tyres till they are very worn and tube starts to bulge through a tiny bit." Maybe you should use your tires until you can no longer read the pressure info on the side. This may well reduce the risk of injury-causing puncture/blow out while riding.

@ojs thanks for the comment. I wasn't suggesting there was a conspiracy - rather that it might be a conscious choice on part of some tyre manufacturers to encourage close inspection of their tyre side-walls. But from other answers and comments it seems that it isn't.

No, it is not intentionally hard to read. It is just shaped in the mould from the rubber material, but on reasonably new tyres, it is not that hard to read. The manufacturer's logo is a sort of advertisement, so it is made to be more visible to other people. Also, the pressures used on tyres of similar sizes often use a similar range of pressures so one just remembers what is the of pressure one should use, especially when re-filling the pressure regularly.

A cynical thought - but I'm sure some tyres are the same as open-mold frames from the Far East, and get branded with whatever name the importer wants.  Whereas the pressure statement will always be the same for that type of tyre so is permanent whereas the printed-on logo can vary without a new stamping die.

@Criggie Not only far east ;-) I've read for example that the "Made in France" Pirelli's gravel tires are made by Hutchinson. I don't know enough tires manufacturing, but given the visual similarities between the tires, it wouldn't be unreasonable to assume that the carcass is indeed shared, and only the tread and outer rubber changes. Printing on the mold would indeed be a way to be sure that legally required info is on the tire, regardless of the 'final' brand - that would also be true within a brand, for different ranges, that being said.

Not just Pirelli. I doubt there are French bike tire manufacturers other than Michelin and Hutchinson, and Mavic "made in France" tires happen to have exactly matching specs with Hutchinson. Even the rubber compound had similar name but the tread was different. And of course some Suomi Tyres models have "Nokian" or even "Nokia" moulded on them even though the company has changed names.

The pressures listed on bike tires are only the maximum and/or minimum pressure, not the optimal pressure.  Optimal pressure is dependent on tire width, rider weight, front-to-back weight distribution, intended use of the bike, and rider preference, and will normally be somewhere between the min and max.
An example of a tire pressure chart is on this website.  The example there only covers tire widths of 20-37mm, so if your tires are wider, you may need to find another chart, although the principles of setting optimal tire pressure are explained there.
So the answer to your question is compare your results to the min and max pressures marked on the tire one time, and then just record your final pressure and ignore the pressures marked on the tire.

Yes. In other words, experienced cyclists seldom read tyre pressure ratings at all. Rather, they know approximately what kinds of pressure are ok for different kinds of tyre, and the exact value is chosen based on preference for what kind of ride they're doing on the day. I'd add that it is often possible to run a tyre even substantially below or above its stated min/max rating, which can sometimes make sense for example when riding on sand or for doing road riding on a mountainbike. Of course, both comes with somewhat increased risk of pinch flats / blowouts, respectively.

@leftaroundabout Even for normal riding (not on sand), as a somewhat lighter rider I usually find myself using less than the minimum pressure for MTB tires. For example with my Bontrager SE4, it's rated for 30-50psi, whereas I use 22.

@MaplePanda Many hybrid bike tires are also IMO designed for way too high pressures, and I tend to end up at the very low end of the rec. range on continental and schwalbe tires. I'm pretty average weight-wise, and every pressure calculator out there (and my bottom) suggest pressures close to or even below low range for many of their tires. Still only had one pinch flat over several years.

The tire specifications, including recommended pressure, is usually (I've never seen an exception) molded in the tire, not written/added on later. This makes it a bit harder to read, but the specs stay on the tire basically forever.
I think this is more of an intended feature than a bug. I doubt it is to make people inspect tires more thoroughly. It might be that they put different graphics on the same tire to brand it differently, but either way, molding the specs onto the tire is IMO a good engineering practice. Perhaps it is even mandatory.
According to Wikipedia, it seems to be mandatory for automotive tires, and most bike tire manufacturers probably just kept this practice in their production:

Automotive tires are described by an alphanumeric tire code (in North American English) or tyre code (in Commonwealth English), which is generally molded into the sidewall of the tire. This code specifies the dimensions of the tire, and some of its key limitations, such as load-bearing ability, and maximum speed. [...]


The DOT code[1] is an alphanumeric character sequence molded into the sidewall of the tire and allows the identification of the tire and its age. The code is mandated by the U.S. Department of Transportation[2] but is used worldwide.[3]


It is certainly not always molded. My Tufo Thunderos have all writings in color on the sidewall including the pressure ranges.

I did write "usually", but thanks for establishing that there are manufacturers that type it on after the molding is done.
